# \marginskip not working in marginfix

Tags: marginpar

Can someone enlighten me on the correct usage of the `\marginskip` command from [`marginfix`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginfix)? Reading the documentation I thought issuing it will force separation between individual `\marginpars`, but I can't quite get it to work. I've tried putting the `\marginskip` command in the preamble, on the page, on a different page, in the pagestyle setting, and it doesn't appear to do anything at all!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginfix}

\begin{document}

Some text \marginskip{20pt} 
\marginpar{just a bunch of text long enough to break a line}
Some more text
\marginpar{a bit more text long enough to break a line}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Expected: some space between the two `\marginpar`s.

Comment: FWIW: I know I can `\setlength\marginparpush...` to get the separation. This question is specifically about the `marginfix` package documentation and whether I am severely misreading something.

Comment: I think you are misreading it, as far as i can see it just adds one skip to the margin at the point that you use it, so you would need to use it between these two marginpar, but actually within the paragraph it seems not to work, it works if they are in separate paragraphs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the command working adding 20pt at the corresponding point in the list of marginpar if you uncomment it here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginfix}

\begin{document}

Some text 
\marginpar{just a bunch of text long enough to break a line}
Some more text

%\marginskip{20pt}
\marginpar{a bit more text long enough to break a line}
\end{document}
```

But without the paragraph break I don't see any effect in this case, which seems to be an undocumented feature of the package.... (the 20pt gets added to the internal list first, before the two marginpar, and then, as documented, skips at the top of the margin are discarded)

This version shows no skip in the output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginfix}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

Some text 
\marginpar{just a bunch of text long enough to break a line}
Some more text
\marginskip{20pt}
\marginpar{a bit more text long enough to break a line}
\typeout{\meaning\mfx@marginlist}

\typeout{\meaning\mfx@marginlist}

\end{document}
```

but shows a log of

```
macro:->\mfx@build@skip {20pt}
macro:->\mfx@build@skip {20pt}\mfx@build@note \bx@B \bx@A {1.60004pt}\mfx@build
@skip {5.0pt}\mfx@build@note \bx@D \bx@C {1.60004pt}\mfx@build@skip {5.0pt}
```

so before the paragraph ends, the list just has the skip, and after it, the list has the skip first (which is then discarded) followed by the two marginpar.

Comment: Hmmm... looking at the definition of `\softclearmargin` this undocumented "feature" also implies the feature that it would only prevent new margin pars from being added by the subsequent paragraphs, and not the current one.